# Eclipse / RAD run menu vanished

Tags: java, eclipse, execute, rad

I had a project and everything was working and then for some reasons I had to do a new checkout from the repository and now my IDE is not working. Where there used to be a menu for run as application---there is now only some mobile selection. I just want to run this as a java class. Why can't I?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the "perspective" selected in top right corner of eclipse? Its possible that this was changed to mobile developement. You can also check "Project Nature" in your .project file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Src is not a source folder, so your source is not compiled and cannot be run.  The hollow J in the icon indicates exactly this.

Add src to the build path.

Comment: But how? I don't see that option. I use IBM RAD 8 that is not working.

Comment: Right-click on "src" and look at the Build Path sub-menu (if built on a reasonably recent Eclipse)

Comment: There is no build path sub-menu since I use IBM RAD 8 that is not working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Nick Rosencrantz - it is in the project properties under [Java Build Path](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/radhelp/v8/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm)

Comment: @NickRosencrantz the image in your question shows a pop-up menu.  That menu contains a "Build Path >" entry!